# Sonata error during loading data

Tags: symfony, sonata

I have an error when i'm executing Sonata's command to load the data :

```
php bin/load_data.php
```

My console return me the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) 
in /Projets/LGAV/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2675
An error occurs when running a command!
```

I don't know how to fix it...

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to increase memory limit in **php.ini**?
*memory_limit* config param is 128MB by default, sometimes it could be too small value.